# Write formatted strings to text file?

Tags: c#, file-io

Brand new to C#, and programming in general.

I'm having a heck of a time finding an answer to this question with Google. I've seen dozens of results that cover *how* to write strings to a text file, but what I can't find out is if it's possible to write a formatted string to a text file (and have it retain its formatting, of course). Right now, my program writes a few lines of information that I want to use as a header for a log file. I don't think I can use Console.SetOut because I only want to write this header once, and then only append the text file with new information (also in the form of formatted strings) thereafter.

So, here's the console output. This output is formatted exactly the way I want to see it written to the text file the program also creates:

[image]

And the code that writes that output:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ut = "1Y, 4D, 01:23:45";
        string met = "T+4D, 01:11:32";
        string mission = "Kapollo";
        string vesselName = "Saturn K";
        string vesselModules = "Command/Service Module;Munar Excursion Module";
        string kerbals = "Valentina Kerman, Pilot;Jebediah Kerman, Pilot;Bill Kerman, Engineer;Bob Kerman, Scientist\n";

        string[] headerNames = { "UT:", "MET:", "Mission:", "Vessel:", "Modules:", "Crew:" };
        string[] headerData = new string[6] { ut, met, mission, vesselName, vesselModules, kerbals };

        Console.WriteLine("Mission Log Computer Initialized\n");

        for (int index = 0; index < headerNames.Length; index++)
        {

            var items = headerData[index].Split(';');   //splits the string when a ';' is present
            if (items.Length > 1)   //if there is more than one item in a string, do this:
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-46}", headerNames[index], items[0]);   //writes headerName as usual. Not sure what items[0] does
                for (int i = 1; i < items.Length; i++)  //for every item in the string, increment 'i' by 1
                {
                    // Render the following items.
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-46}", string.Empty, items[i]);
                    //^^^writes a blank entry where headerName would print using string.Empty, and then writes 'i', but I'm not sure how 'i' ends up containing multiple strings
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,-12} {1,-46}", headerNames[index], headerData[index]);    //otherwise, do this
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not clear what you want; do you want to send the formatted output to a text file instead of the command window? In addition to? Do you want to write different things to the text file than to the command window? What is different?

Comment: @DourHighArch sorry, yeah, I want to write this information as formatted to a text file instead of to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class, in that code snippet I just replaced Console.WriteLine statement by a StringBuilder.AppendLine and StringBuilder.AppendFormat :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string ut = "1Y, 4D, 01:23:45";
    string met = "T+4D, 01:11:32";
    string mission = "Kapollo";
    string vesselName = "Saturn K";
    string vesselModules = "Command/Service Module;Munar Excursion Module";
    string kerbals = "Valentina Kerman, Pilot;Jebediah Kerman, Pilot;Bill Kerman, Engineer;Bob Kerman, Scientist\n";

    string[] headerNames = { "UT:", "MET:", "Mission:", "Vessel:", "Modules:", "Crew:" };
    string[] headerData = new string[6] { ut, met, mission, vesselName, vesselModules, kerbals };

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Mission Log Computer Initialized");
    builder.AppendLine();

    for (int index = 0; index < headerNames.Length; index++)
    {
        var items = headerData[index].Split(';');   //splits the string when a ';' is present
        if (items.Length > 1)   //if there is more than one item in a string, do this:
        {
            builder.AppendFormat("{0,-12} {1,-46}", headerNames[index], items[0]);   //writes headerName as usual. Not sure what items[0] does
            builder.AppendLine();
            for (int i = 1; i < items.Length; i++)  //for every item in the string, increment 'i' by 1
            {
                // Render the following items.
                builder.AppendFormat("{0,-12} {1,-46}", string.Empty, items[i]);
                builder.AppendLine();
                //^^^writes a blank entry where headerName would print using string.Empty, and then writes 'i', but I'm not sure how 'i' ends up containing multiple strings
            }
        }
        else
        {
            builder.AppendFormat("{0,-12} {1,-46}", headerNames[index], headerData[index]);    //otherwise, do this
            builder.AppendLine();
        }
    }

    string result = builder.ToString();
    File.WriteAllText("PATH TO THE FILE", result);
}
```

Comment: "string result = builder.ToString();
// Write result to a file"

I'm a little unclear now what precisely I'm using in order to append a file. Do I still use File.AppendAllText(path, <string>); —where path is obviously the path to the file I want to write to, and <string> would be 'result'?

Comment: @blorgon You want to append the result to an existing file or create a new one ?

Comment: Wanted to write the result to a new file, the function for which I already have written. I used File.AppendAllText because I'm under the assumption that I should use that in order to never delete anything from the file, only add new things to it.

Worked like a charm. Thanks so much!

Comment: Your welcome. I updated my answer, showing how to write it to a file, it will create a new file or replace existing.

Comment: I have a new question! How do I get this to only write that particular block once, the very first time the program has been run? I'm planning on adding other data streams that will need to be added to the text file over time, but I need it to be read as a contiguous stream of information, without any duplicates. That "block" of information you helped me write will only serve as a header for the file of sorts.

Comment: Then wrap this code snippet in a method that will be called at your program startup. You can use a static boolean flag to ensure that it will be called once.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to send text to a file instead of to the command window, change all `Console.WriteLine` in your program to `Console.Out.WriteLine`. Then run your application from a command window like this:

```
YourProgramName >textFileName.txt
```

Comment: Eventually, this .exe is actually going to need to be a .dll that I'm going to install in a game directory. I need the program to run automatically, triggered by an event in the game, as opposed to having to run it manually via a command line.